# Mailchimp drupal 7 success message

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, mailchimp

Hi I've successfully implemented the mailchimp form and the entries are being posted to my mailchimp list.

However I'm not able to output a success message to the user. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6) function allows you to output status, warning, and error messages to a page.

Though there's not an official release of the [Mailchimp](https://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module, you may want to look into using it, instead of developing your own Mailchimp integration module.